# Difference Dates Calculation

Tags: asp.net

I   have  three  textboxes, `StartTextbox`, `EndTextBox`, and `Textbox3`, where `Textbox3` contains `No of Month`. Now I want difference of start date and end date to be checked     against `No of Month`.

Here is the custom validation function:

```
protected void ValidateDuration(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(StartTextBox.Text);
    DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(EndTextBox.Text);

    int months = (end.Month - start.Month) + 12 * (end.Year - start.Year);

    e.IsValid = months <= TextBox3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check `months` (an `int`) with the value of `TextBox3`, you'll have to first get the value as a `string` and convert it to an `int`. For example:

```
protected void ValidateDuration(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(StartTextBox.Text);
    DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(EndTextBox.Text);

    int months = (end.Month - start.Month) + 12 * (end.Year - start.Year);
    int noOfMonth = int.Parse(TextBox3.Text);

    e.IsValid = months <= noOfMonth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of months between two date by using the overridden operation - to get a time span between 2 dates:

```
    DateTime date1 = new DateTime();
    DateTime date2 = new DateTime();

    date1 = DateTime.Now;
    date2 = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(4);

    TimeSpan months = date2 - date1;

   Console.WriteLine(months.Days / 30);
```

This code snippet will display 4 months

for your code:

```
e.IsValid = months <= Int32.TryParse(TextBox3.Text);
```